# C# DeflateStream.Read() giving an InvalidDataException

Tags: c#, memorystream, string-conversion, compression, deflatestream

I want to unzip a compressed string so that the string of characters would become usable.

I successfully extract in an array of bytes the content of a downloaded file with the function WebClient.DownloadData(String).

*The characters are logically compressed with the deflate method, because 7-Zip is giving this information when I download the file (in varying extensions) :*

[Compressed file informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njCBt.png)

Thus, I am supposed to use the DeflateStream class to be able to decode the string, with the function Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count) ; reading a MemoryStream.

I use a simple function which I can find online :

```
public string UnzipString2(byte[] byteArrayCompressedContent)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArrayCompressedContent, 0);
                    memoryStream.Write(byteArrayCompressedContent, 4, byteArrayCompressedContent.Length - 4);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;

                    var buffer = new byte[dataLength];

                    using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(memoryStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        deflateStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        deflateStream.Close();
                    }
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

When we call the Read() function, it is giving an InvalidDataException : Found in valid data while decoding ; with the stacktrace

> at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.DecodeDynamicBlockHeader()\r\n    at
>   System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Decode()\r\n    at
>   System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 length)\r\n    at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count)\r\n

However, I still think that the information are compressed with the "deflate method".
**Is there a different/better/working way to read the data and decompress it in a String?**

Answer (score 0):

Compressing a string onto a MemoryStream is not the same as compressing a file as a zip or similar. Even in the compressing algorithm is the same, a compressed file has headers that can be used by the decoder to get information, not only about the compression itself, but also about the files inside of it.

Therefore, if you are trying to deflate a file with the DeflateStream function, the header will not have the expected format, which is exactly what the DecodeDynamicBlockHeader error is telling you.

Comment: I think I'm not trying to deflate a file but a MemoryStream from an array of bytes returned by he function WebClient.DownloadData(). Thus, DeflateStream() should be appropriate ?

Comment: I can't know for sure because it depends what your source is, but I suspect that if 7zip opens it, it should be a compressed *file* and as such you should decompress it with an unzip method / library.